# Next steps for solving DAE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm new to [differential algebraic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebraic_equation), and I need some guidance.

I have a DAE of the following form:

$$
\begin{align}
x'_1 &= f_1(x_1)      \\
x'_2 &= f_2(x_1, x_2) \\
x'_3 &= f_3(x_1, x_3) \\
0    &= C - x_1 + x_2 + x_3 
\end{align}
$$

where $C$ is a real-valued, non-zero constant.

Although there are hints that $x_1(t)$ can be solved analytically, the solution isn't going to be pretty. In general, I'm more interested in numerical solutions to this and similar problems. Because I'm using MATLAB to solve it, I have to reformulate this DAE to an index-1 problem of the form

$$
M\mathbf{x}' = F(t, \mathbf{x})
$$

with $M$ the system's mass matrix. Now, if I happily implement everything like this:

$$
\begin{align}
M &= \left[ \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix} \right]\\
\mathbf{x} &= \left[\begin{matrix}x_1 \\x_2\\x_3\\C\end{matrix}\right] \\
F &= \left[\begin{matrix}f_1(x_1)\\f_2(x_1,x_2)\\f_3(x_1,x_3)\\C-x_1+x_2+x_3\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}
$$

then MATLAB complains that the system has a differential index greater than 1 (which I don't really understand).

In an attempt to reduce the index, I take the derivative of the constraint equation:

$$
x'_1 = x'_2 + x'_3 
$$

which makes it tempting to set

$$
\begin{align}
M &= \left[ \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix} \right]\\
F &= \left[\begin{matrix}f_1(x_1)\\f_2(x_1,x_2)\\f_3(x_1,x_3)\\0\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}
$$

but then I will have lost the constraint involving $C$ (aside from using it to find consistent initial values).

Another train of thought was that the derivative of the constraint implies

$$
f_1(x_1) = f_2(x_1, x_2) + f_3(x_1, x_3)
$$

which, together with a constraint on the initial values implied by the (undifferentiated) constraint equation, as well as an analytical solution of $x_1(t)$, would possibly allow me to find $x_2(t)$ and $x_3(t)$ directly. But that seems rather more difficult than "just" doing it numerically—if not impossible.

I'm stuck and all out of ideas. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: +1 for the good question. Just a side note you should not use different function names for systems like this rather use $x_1'=f_1(x_1)$, $x_2'=f_2(x_1,x_2)$ and so forth. It is better to work like this especially if you want to implement this in a program and you directly know that $f_n$ belongs to the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative.

Comment: @MrYouMath thanks. You're right to point out my notation problem, however, in my implementation $f$, $g$ and $h$ are the results of copious substitutions to reduce the original system of size 24 down to the size 3 shown above. They are therefore also used in places other than just the 3 derivatives shown above. Nevertheless, I'll change the notation used above, because my reality involves details not needed here 

Comment: Is $C$ an unknown (seems yes)? Is it supposed to be a constant? If $C$ is just another function, then you have the most simple explicit index 1 system, if it is a constant then you have 4 equations for 3 variables, which is overdetermined and in general unsolvable.

Comment: @LutzL sorry, forgot to mention that $C$ is a real-valued, non-zero constant.

Comment: @LutzL I just put it into the state vector, because I wasn't sure what else to put there – I just used it as a dummy, which is probably not correct, I know.

Comment: Then Matlab is correct to refuse to solve this. If the derived equation between the functions is not automatically satisfied, there will be almost surely no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\begin{align}
x'_1 &= f_1(x_1)      \\
x'_2 &= f_2(x_1, x_2) \\
x'_3 &= f_3(x_1, x_3) \\
0    &= C - x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \implies x_3=x_1-x_2-C \implies x_3'=x_1'-x_2'
\end{align}
$$

As far as I can see the first two equations are decoupled from the third. You can use the first and the second differential equation to determine $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then use the third to validate that the solutions do satisfy 
$$x_3'=x_1'-x_2'=f_1(x_1)-f_2(x_1,x_2)=f_3(x_1,x_1-x_2-C).$$

**Note**, you could also check the last algebraic equation for consistency without solving the other ODEs. If it is valid then you can try to solve the first two equations and then determine the last solution by $x_3=x_1-x_2-C$. I think this way is better because you will not have to cope with numerical inaccuracies for validating the constraint equation.

Comment: Is it not better to say that the first 3 equations determine the dynamic completely, and that if the resulting $C$ is not a constant function, the system is not solvable?

Comment: Thank you. So, to make a numerical recipe out of this: choosing initial values for $x_1^0 = x_1(t_0)$ and  $x_2^0 = x_2(t_0)$ constrains the initial value $x_3^0 = x_3(t_0) = x_1^0-x_2^0-C$. With the initial values $x_1^0$ and $x_2^0$, solve $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ numerically. Using the initial value $x_3^0$, solve $x_3(t)$ numerically, substituting $x_1(t) - x_2(t) - C$ into $f_3$. Is that correct? I'm not subtracting $x'_1 - x'_2$ anywhere...

Comment: @LutzL: I also do not completely understand the sense of this system. (at) Rody Oldenhuis. You can also subtract the right-hand sides and directly see if the system is consistent or not without solving the first two equations. It is just to validate if the given solutions do satisfy the constraint equation or not.